# Page not loading after installing Zend Guard Loader

Tags: php, zend-guard

After I installed Zend Guard Loader 5.6 with PHP Version 5.6.32, the page shows error "The server didn’t send any data". I also checked `phpinfo`, and it showed that Zend Guard Loader already installed.

Can anyone help me? Thanks...